# Other Ways Besides JMF to Play Media in Java

Tags: java, video, audio, media, jmf

I am currently using JMF. The reason why I am straying from JMF is the lack of format support. I have looked into FMJ and have not had much luck getting it to run. Recording media is not an issue, I just need a way to display it. My application is swing based. Anyone recommend a library or framework that they have worked with that is good for playing media. Could you tell me about your experience with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ..Recording media is not an issue, I just need a way to display it. ..

Look into the [Java Bindings for VideoLAN](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/).

> ..Could you tell me about your experience with it?

I've not used it.  JMF is good enough for my immediate purposes.

Comment: Wow, this seemed like to be the exact solution I was looking for until I saw the license. My product is commercial so I wont be able to use it. But still really cool software nonetheless. Thanks!